# Other parsed contents of a static HTML webpage?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am creating a Python web-scraper, and I have it print the `title` and `span` of the web-page I enter. I've been looking around, but cannot find other elements to a web-page.

Are there any other portions of a website which Python can access using `bs4` / `BeautifulSoup` / `requests`?

I've found a `head` element, but I'm sure there has to be more.

Comment: Will you update your answer to show us what you have tried so far? Also to note: there's the `body` tag which is a sibling of the `head` tag.

Comment: some pages may use own tags which you can't find in HTML specification. And pages may have extra tags inside `<canvas>`, `<svg>`, `<mathml>`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/) is a list of HTML tags you can find. In bs4, you  generally use the `find` or `findAll` methods to scrape a page. The first parameter of these functions is the name of the tag you are in search for. Here are some examples of how to use the findAll method: `https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method:%20findAll(name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20**kwargs)` (Stackoverflow would not let me paste the link as a hyperlink)

Alternatively you can traverse the document tree like so:

```py
def walker(soup):
    if soup.name is not None:
        for child in soup.children:
            #process node
            print str(child.name) + ":" + str(type(child)) 
            walker(child)

walker(soup)
```

taken from: http://makble.com/parsing-and-traversing-dom-tree-with-beautifulsoup

This goes through each node in the tree from the root, `<html>` in a depth-first search. This is done by recursively looking at the children of each node, then the children's children and so on.